# Node.js, проблема с require

Tags: node.js, prototype, require

Приложение на node.js
Есть main.js, в нём:

```
require('./tools.js');
console.log(Number.isNumeric(111));
```

Далее, есть tools.js, в нём:

```
Number.prototype.isNumeric = function (n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
};
```

Результат:

```
    console.log(Number.isNumeric(111));
                   ^

TypeError: Number.isNumeric is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/eman/bestapp_backend/lib/main.js:21:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at startup (node.js:160:18)
    at node.js:456:3
```

Собственно вопрос, че делать и как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fix:

```
Number.isNumeric = function (n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
};
```